# Weighted Fleiss' Kappa for Interval Data

Tags: agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I am looking for a variant of Fleiss' Kappa to deal with interval data, rather than strictly nominal/ordinal data.  The context that I intend to use it in is as follows:

- There are several (5-8) graders grading a total of 16 exams
- The exams are identical, and contain 7 questions.
- Each question is graded out of 3-8, depending on the question
- Every exam is graded by every grader (though there are spots of missing data)

Please help me find where to look!  I have seen an occasional internet utterance of a weighted Fleiss' Kappa, but never a reference for it.  I have hope that it exists because a weighted Cohen's Kappa is used frequently.  References to relevant R packages would also be appreciated (I have used the irr package before).

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question title to make it clear you want something that applies to interval data?

Comment: @Silverfish, thank you for the suggestion, I have made that edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the generalized formula for Fleiss' kappa:
$$r_{ik}^\star = \sum_{l=1}^q w_{kl}r_{il}$$
$$p_o = \frac{1}{n'}\sum_{i=1}^{n'}\sum_{k=1}^{q}\frac{r_{ik}(r_{ik}^\star-1)}{r_i(r_i-1)}$$
$$\pi_k = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{r_{ik}}{r_i}$$
$$p_c = \sum_{k,l}^q w_{kl} \pi_k \pi_l$$
$$\widehat{\kappa} = \frac{p_o-p_c}{1-p_c}$$
where $q$ is the total number of categories,
$w_{kl}$ is the weight associated with two raters assigning an item to categories $k$ and $l$,
$r_{il}$ is the number of raters that assigned item $i$ to category $l$,
$n'$ is the number of items that were coded by two or more raters,
$r_{ik}$ is the number of raters that assigned item $i$ to category $k$,
$r_i$ is the number of raters that assigned item $i$ to any category,
and $n$ is the total number of items.

Here is the formula for calculating interval weights:
$$w_{kl} = \begin{cases}1-\frac{|x_k-x_l|}{x_{max}-x_{min}} & \text{if } k \neq l\\1 & \text{if }k=l\end{cases}$$
where the weight of any two categories $k$ and $l$ is equal to $1$ minus the distance between these categories divided by the maximum distance between any two possible categories.

I have more information on my [mReliability](http://mreliability.jmgirard.com) website, including the **mSCOTTPI** function which will calculate the Fleiss' kappa coefficent in MATLAB. Or if you prefer R, you can use the **fleiss.kappa.raw** function from the [agree.coeff3.raw.r](http://agreestat.com/r_functions.html) package, albeit with less documentation.